# Bash combine multiple commands into a one liner

Tags: linux, bash, unix

Is there a way to combine the following into a nifty "one liner":

```
echo "free -m" > /tmp/dC4v2cK
bash /tmp/dC4v2cK
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish here? Seems like you're trying to take the long way around...

Comment: I think I figured it out, would simply piping work:

`echo "free -m" | bash`

Comment: Or just "free -m". Why the extra bash shell?

Comment: Because what is instead of the echo statement is dynamic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Or if you really want a subshell:

```
/bin/bash -c "free -m"
```

Answer (score 5):

I think you are looking for `eval` (as in `foo='free -m'; eval $foo`).  Keep in mind that doing something like this has security implications if `$foo` is coming from an untrusted source then you could inadvertently do bad things.  For example what if someone managed to get this line to happen.  `foo='rm -rf /'`

```
$ help eval
eval: eval [arg ...]
    Execute arguments as a shell command.

    Combine ARGs into a single string, use the result as input to the shell,
    and execute the resulting commands.

    Exit Status:
    Returns exit status of command or success if command is null.
```